# calling anonymous function stored in static attribute

Tags: php, class, anonymous-function

so i was kinda coding and i ran into that one (see code)

```
<?php
class Test {

    public static $cb = null;

    public static function run () {
        self::$cb = function () {
            print 'Hello World!' . "\n";
        };

        // self::$cb() throws fatal
        $f = self::$cb; $f(); // <--

    }
}

Test::run();
?>
```

As you can see the call to the anonymous function looks really stupid, and i was questioning myself if there is a more convenient solution to this. I'm on PHP 5.3.27 with Suhosin-Patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use [`call_user_func`](http://www.php.net/call_user_func):

```
call_user_func(self::$cb);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/75625)

Comment: thank you for the quick response, i personally dont really like the call_xxx functions in php and will go with __invoke. but nevertheless your answer is completely correct

Answer (score 0):

Hah, i was just blind -> __invoke() is my friend

```
self::$cb->__invoke()
```